# sql query to update parent with more than two children

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update

I have two tables like these:

```
parents(id:int, name:string, large_family:boolean default false)
children(id:int, name:string, parent_id:foreign key to parents)
```

how can i write a query to update **large_family** field in parent to **true** if a parent has more than two children.
thank you

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, oracle...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases, you can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
update parents
set large_family = 1
where (select count(*) from children c where c.parent_id = parent.id) > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a subquery in the SET set clause to set the large_family field for all rows, or you could use a subquery in the WHERE clause to only set it for rows with more than 2 children. Here is an example using the SET clause:

```
UPDATE p
SET p.large_family = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM children c WHERE c.parent_id = p.id) > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM parents p
```

Comment: Note: This is the type of information that you might consider including in a VIEW instead - which will lower the maintenance overhead of updating the parent table every time a child is added or removed.